# Printing of every first elements of a 2-dimensional array

Tags: javascript

Am trying to print out every first elements of each array followed by next element on the index, this is my progress so far...

```
var data = ['x', [1, 2, 3,4], ['a', 'b','c', 'd'], ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV']];

for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    console.log(data[i][j]);  
  }
}
```

my first result is 1aI, how can I print 2bII, 3cIII, 4dIV

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm should be like this:

```
For each column:
   value = ""
   For each row: 
      combine value with the element
   print value
```

```js
var data = ['x', [1, 2, 3,4], ['a', 'b','c', 'd'], ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV']];

for (var j = 0; j < data[1].length; j++) {
  
  var value = "";
 
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    value = value + data[i][j];  
  }
  
  console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = ['x', [1, 2, 3,4], ['a', 'b','c', 'd'], ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV']];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   output = '';
   for (var j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
       output += data[j][i];
    }  
      console.log(output);
}
```